# Priestly Blessing: Origin of the Finger Formation

Tags: minhag, birchas-kohanim

When kohanim bless the congregation, they raise their hands and couple two pairs of fingers, as in the image below:

[image]

Older sources refer to this practice as "the raising of the hands", and it can be found in many ancient texts, including the Mishna (for example: Berakhot 5:4, Megillah 4:5 and 4:7, etc).

What is the oldest source for the coupling of fingers as shown in the image?

Comment: Not all raise their hands like that, see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4598/759 and also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26069/759

Comment: כפים means palms, not hands, no?

Comment: Hebrew http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/art/nesiat/ben-uri-2.htm

Answer (score 1):

In Beer Hagola SA OC 128, on [sayif 12](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x494), the Beer hagola (ot ק ) cited the Rosh in Megila [perek 3, siman 21](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37957&st=&pgnum=481) in name of Midrash (Tanchuma Parashat Nasso siman 8<sup>(1)</sup>, according to Beur Hagra). Here is the Rosh words we see that the two thumbs must be separated. The Rosh interpreted in Tanchuma that there are 5 spaces between Etsbaot, see accurately the hagahat Harashash:

> ומה שחולקים אצבעותיהם זהו לפי המדרש מציץ מן החרכים ששכינה למעלה מראשיהן ומציץ מבין חרכי אצבעותיהן. ומכוונים לעשות חמש אוירים בין שתי אצבעות לשתי אצבעות ובין אצבע לאגודל ובין גודל לגודל לקיים מציץ מן ה' חרכים {כך הגיה הרשש את לשון הרא"ש}  ‏

But the Levushe Serad says on MA sk 19 said that the space between the two thumbs is vertical, not horizontal. The same Magen Avraham said in name of hagahot Maymoniot that between two words the thumbs need to touch one another. (reported in MB sk 43, with explanation that it is because of weakeness)

So your image is the position between two words, may be also that in a sagital view, you would see a vertical space between the thumbs.

---

<sup>(1)</sup>

> אָמְרָה כְּנֶסֶת יִשְׂרָאֵל לִפְנֵי הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא, רִבּוֹנוֹ שֶׁל עוֹלָם, לַכֹּהֲנִים אַתָּה אוֹמֵר שֶׁיְּבָרְכוּ אוֹתָנוּ. אֵין אָנוּ צְרִיכִין אֶלָּא לְבִרְכָתְךָ וְלִהְיוֹתֵנוּ מִתְבָּרְכִין מִפִּיךָ, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: הַשְׁקִיפָה מִמְּעוֹן קָדְשְׁךָ. אָמַר לָהֶם הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא, אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁאָמַרְתִּי לַכֹּהֲנִים שֶׁיְּהוּ מְבָרְכִין אֶתְכֶם, אֲנִי עוֹמֵד עִמָּהֶם וּמְבָרֵךְ אֶתְכֶם. לְפִיכָךְ הַכֹּהֲנִים פּוֹרְשִׂין אֶת כַּפֵּיהֶם, לוֹמַר, שֶׁהַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא עוֹמֵד אַחֲרֵינוּ. וְכֵן הוּא אוֹמֵר, הִנֵּה זֶה עוֹמֵד אַחַר כָּתְלֵנוּ מַשְׁגִּיחַ מִן הַחַלּוֹנוֹת **מֵצִיץ מִן הַחֲרַכִּים** (שה"ש ב, ט), מַה **בֵּין אֶצְבָּעוֹת שֶׁל כֹּהֲנִים.** מֵצִיץ מִן הַחֲרַכִּים, בְּשָׁעָה שֶׁפּוֹשְׁטִין כַּפֵּיהֶם. לְכָךְ נֶאֱמַר: כֹּה תְּבָרְכוּ אֶת בְּנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל. ‏

Answer (score 0):

The oldest might be found in archaeology

For example the [grave stone of the shach](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/he/4/46/Shabbatai_HaKohen%27s_grave.jpeg)

A [few stones from 1840-1860](http://www.jewish-heritage.org.il/subcontentpage.aspx?id=214)

[14th century cemetery in lido](http://m.masa.co.il/article/1815/%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%97-%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%94/)

---

The 2 index fingers usually touch each other

See answers here
[Significance of the Kohen's hand gestures?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26069/5120)

---

My answer from there

This video starting 1:30.
https://youtu.be/VVjP9mzOEE4?t=1m30s

Explains that this gesture is to have Hashem's name

The shin with the thumbs.
The daled (with the numerical value of 4) with the 4 groups of 2 fingers 
The yid (with the numerical value of 10) with the 10 fingers in total