# Kohen Duchaning with First Two Fingers Together

Tags: halacha, kohen-priest, birchas-kohanim, hands-fingers

I recently saw some drawings of the Kohen's hands during duchaning, not the way I do it. I put my two first fingers together without leaving a window. I would like to know if there is any valid way that includes putting those two fingers together. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Mort, welcome to Mi Yodeya and thanks for bringing your question here. It might be helpful to give a little more information in your question as to what you saw and how it differs from what you understand to be correct. Even better would be to cite any source material you are aware of regarding this topic.

Comment: Since you haven't specified what your hand gesture is, it's impossible to know whether your way is valid. I'm closing this as "ambiguous, vague, incomplete". If you make it more specific, please leave a comment here with `@msh210` and I'll be glad to reopen it. Note though that the answers at http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4598 may answer your question.

Comment: @msh210, what do you mean? "I put my two first fingers together without leaving a window."

Comment: However, this may be a dupe of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4598/5

Comment: @SethJ, how is anyone to know whether that way is valid if he doesn't specify what he does with the rest of his fingers?

Comment: @msh210, ah, well, I thought the question was about placement of those fingers in particular.

Comment: @SethJ, okay, I've [edited](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/27759/revisions) and will reopen.

Comment: @msh210 SethJ So the question is now are there any opinions for holding the hands during the priestly blessing which include keeping the index and middle fingers touching each other?

Comment: @DoubleAA, that's the only way I could read the question that allows it to be answered. Unless you have a better idea? (Obviously, Mort, you should re-edit the question to better reflect your intent if I've mangled it.)

Comment: @DoubleAA, I have no idea what the original question meant with regard to placement of the fingers. I just understood him to be describing his thumb and forefinger closed, which ought to be understandable to a Kohen.

Comment: @SethJ, oh, and I understood him as referring to his index and middle fingers. Heh.

Comment: @SethJ What do you mean "ought to be understandable to a Kohen"?

Comment: @DoubleAA, I think a description of placement of "first and second fingers" and "windows" ought to be standard usage among Kohanim. I'm not a Kohen, but it seems to me a Kohen ought to know what another Kohen is talking about when using those terms.

Comment: @SethJ I think you overestimate the amount of schmoozing kohanim do with each other while going out to wash :)

Comment: @double aa, do the fathers not teach the sons?

Comment: @SethJ I'm sure some do, but even so with duchening so rare in the diaspora, I know I was surprised when noticing sometimes how little the kohanim knew about the details of what they were doing.

Comment: @DoubleAA fair enough (though rather sad).

Answer (score 1):

The first answer to [Kohanic Hand Gestures?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4598/kohanic-hand-gestures) (YDK Dec 15 '10 at 0:49)
gives what I believe is the normative method as I think you describe it.

The last answer (DoubleAA  Nov 11 '11 at 4:38) is the custom of the Gr"A where "you spread out all the fingers".

Could it be that you saw a drawing of the postioning of the fingers according to the Gr"A?

Comment: Answers appear in different orders at different times and to different people. you may wish to identify them with links and/or by authorship and not by number.